# Identifying the meaning of こんなこと in this context

Tags: reading-comprehension

For the full text see [here](http://bmbuf.web.fc2.com/lib/hosip/ai_no_kagi.pdf). A girl has had an argument with her boyfriend. On the way home she thinks that maybe she should have apologised. She's now changing the password on her room door.

> ぼんやりと字をいじっているうちに、字は「悪かった、ごめんなさい。」と並んでいた。いまさら、**こんなこと**を言っても仕方がないのに、**あたしもばかね**。だけど、あすから、**この言葉**を言ってすごすわ。
> While absentmindedly messing with the characters, the phrase "It's my fault. Sorry."  was lined up. Even though it's no use saying such a thing at this late stage, I'm an idiot, aren't I? However, tomorrow I'll spend time saying these words.

I don't fully understand this passage. What does こんなこと refer to here? Is it the phrase 悪かった、ごめんなさい or is it あたしもばかね. i.e. Is she saying that there's not point in calling herself an idiot, or is she saying there's no point in saying it was her fault?

Presumably この言葉 refers to 悪かった、ごめんなさい? I'm not confident that I'm putting all this together correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both こんなこと and この言葉 refer to 「悪かった、ごめんなさい。」

By あたしもばかね, she's saying it's foolish of her to change the password to "I am sorry" (so that she'd have to say it to the door every day from tomorrow), even though there's no point in saying it anymore.

だけど、あす**から**、この言葉を言ってすごすわ literally means "However, from tomorrow I'll spend time saying these words", practically means she will use that phrase as the password and say it every day.